# EF Migrations Applying to LocalDB instead of Azure Server DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Adding and updating Entity Framework Migrations using the VS console and dotnet cli does not affect the Azure Server DB. Changes are applied to the localDB.

The connection string is correctly set in appsettings.json

Answer (score 0):

When both Entity Framework Core and Entity Framework 6 are installed, EF6 is used.
My setup uses EFC so in the VS console or dotnet cli, I should use

```
EntityFrameworkCore\Update-Database
```

Comment: There is also the dotnet cli. `> dotnet ef database update` which will work in PackageManager console and also from any shell. You can install with `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef`